# Cannot get delete key to work with tmux and OSX

Tags: macos, key-bindings, tmux

On OSX with tmux installed through homebrew I cannot seem to get my 'delete' key to work. I am using iterm2 and have my delete mapped to ^H. Without tmux the 'delete' key works fine.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Backspace not working in tmux command prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51488920/backspace-not-working-in-tmux-command-prompt)

Answer (score 5):

To fix backspace on Apple M1 Pro OSX 12.4, tmux 3.3a
I had to do the following

```
brew install ncurses
$(brew --prefix)/opt/ncurses/bin/infocmp tmux-256color > ~/tmux-256color.info
tic -xe tmux-256color ~/tmux-256color.info

#https://github.com/tmux/tmux/issues/1257#issuecomment-581378716
#https://gist.github.com/bbqtd/a4ac060d6f6b9ea6fe3aabe735aa9d95
```

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me is adding this to `.tmux.conf`.

```
# apps should know that this is 'screen' and not xterm. Slight compatibility
# reasons. tmux should be running in xterm-256colors, and set TERM so that
# applications within tmux see screen-256colors tmux does not support -bce
# (background color erase)
set -g default-terminal 'screen-256color'
```

Answer (score 1):

This might be some terminal emulation issue within your shell.

When you are in a tmux session, enter the following in the bash prompt and see if it works:

```
stty erase ^H
```

If this helps, check your terminal tty settings.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this and I found a solution for me.

Tmux uses `^?` for delete. stty was not sending `^?`.

I changed that using `stty erase '^?'` and then changed my preferences in iTerm2 for delete to send `^?`

https://github.com/tmux/tmux/issues/335

Answer (score 0):

I'm a few years late, but for me the problem was my `$TERM` setting ... changed it to `screen-256color` and that did the trick

Better solution here: https://gist.github.com/bbqtd/a4ac060d6f6b9ea6fe3aabe735aa9d95