# I can't use Delete key to delete a character (its normal functioning) in Vim on tmux

Tags: vim, tmux

I played around with tmux config. I love tmux and I don't want to stop using it, but for some reason the delete key doesn't delete anymore. It deletes a character and works normally in vim, but not in vim when opened from tmux. Backspace works fine. Just the delete key stopped working only in vim running on tmux. Any ideas?

Comment: Does the last answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23848061/cannot-get-delete-key-to-work-with-tmux-and-osx) help you? It's here as well, marked as the solution: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/230665/i-cant-delete-in-tmux/231325

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm a newbie to linux. I'm not running osx, just ubuntu and no iterm2. Will it still work? Also, the guy there says Vim is able to delete on tmux, but I can't.

Comment: I don't know to be honest, but try to redefine delete, and if so write an answer for yourself.

Comment: `set t_kb=^V<BS>` and `fixdel` fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You may need to remap the delete key in your .vimrc. For instance, like this:

```
inoremap ^? <c-h>
cnoremap ^? <c-h>

" Debian-specific variation
inoremap <esc>[3~ <c-h>
cnoremap <esc>[3~ <c-h>
```

I have both of these in my .vimrc, and have for years, and it's worked everywhere for me. With or without tmux.

I will note though that the `^?` in the first two lines is **NOT** the characters `^` and `?`, it is a single embedded delete character. The way to insert this is to edit your .vimrc with vim, and use this sequence to insert it:

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>, then press <kbd>Delete</kbd>.

If done properly, Vim should show it to you as a `^?`, but it is a single character in the file. The rest of the lines are typed exactly as they are shown.

This will remap the delete key to send backspace, and you can use them interchangeably.

Comment: When I try to insert the embedded delete character I get ^[[3~ if I use Delete key. But if I use backspace key then I get ^?. Is something wrong? Also I press ctrl v, release them and then press delete. If I do that without releasing then I get different embedded character.

Comment: @Raksh That means your backspace character is sending `^?` (ASCII 0x7F, DEL). And as suggested by my answer, Debian (and likely therefore Ubuntu) uses `<Esc>[3~` for the delete key. So press backspace to get the character in there... and add the other one... and then every variation should send `<Backspace>` and it should work, I think, no matter what you press on the keyboard.

Comment: So by <esc> you mean escape sequence (^[) or am I wrong?

Comment: @Raksh I mean the ESC character, ASCII 0x1B, which Vim represents using `<Esc>`, but in other places shows up as `^[`, yes.

Comment: Tried your answer, it still does not work. FYI, it works when I'm not using vim on tmux. Only when I run vim on tmux, it acts weirdly (it comes out of insert mode when I press delete key and then changes upper case to lower case and vice versa). But, thanks a lot for the quick response.

Comment: @Raksh You could probably configure the terminal program to send something other than `<Esc>[3~` for Delete... but I don't have an Ubuntu GUI handy to figure out how to do that. The terminal app probably has a settings screen or a startup file, though.