# Backspace not working in tmux command prompt

Tags: tmux

I'm having trouble with my Backspace key on the tmux command prompt.  The backspace deletes previous characters (as expected) within tmux but not on the tmux command prompt.  For example, `<PREFIX>:lists<DEL>` will not delete the 's' character.  Using `C-h` instead of the Delete key *does* delete the 's' character in this situation.  `C-?` does NOT delete the 's' character.  Some debugging I've done within the tmux window:

```
$TERM=screen-256color
infocmp reports kbs=\177                  (good)
appres XTerm | grep backarrowKeyIsErase   reports as true (good)
appres XTerm | grep ptyInitialErase       reports as true (good)
stty -a | grep erase                      reports as "^H" (bad, I think I want ^?)
```

I've also tried binding the Backspace key in the `.tmux.conf` as shown below to both `C-h` and `C-?`, neither work.  `:list-keys` within tmux confirms that the mapping is occurring.

```
bind-key -n BSpace send-keys C-?
```

I've done a `stty erase ^?` as well, both before and after invoking `tmux` and that does not affect the behavior.  Finally, I've removed my `.tmux.conf` entirely and still get the same behavior.

Does the command line use a different set of key bindings that would affect BSpace functionality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was because there was a mismatch between my `$TERM` settings, my `.Xdefaults`, the keybindings for the terminal (I use `konsole`) and whatever `tmux` was sending.  My specific fix required getting Backspace set to `^?` everywhere and NOT `^h`.  Additionally, tmux's `$TERM` is best set to screen-256colors or tmux-256colors so you need to ensure that those terminal modes can see the right key mappings.

In my `.Xdefaults`, note that this is for all VT100 and not just XTerm*VT100 because I want screen, tmux, and konsole to see these entries:

```
*VT100.Translations: #override \n\
   <Key>BackSpace:       string(0x7F) \n\
   <Key>Delete:          string("\033[3~")

*ttyModes: erase ^?
```

I also had to fix my bindkeys in my `~/.cshrc`:

```
bindkey -a "\e[3~" delete-char
stty erase ^?
```

... and also add a similar entry to an `~/.inputrc` file (which konsole reads):

```
"\e[3~": delete-char
```

Answer (score 43):

As I got from [Backspace bad behaviour #321](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/issues/321):

> I had the same problem (with backspace plus getting addition characters from auto completion) whenever I entered a tmux session. I removed the .tmux.conf and the problem disappeared so I changed the following in my .tmux.conf
>
> changed from: set -g default-terminal "tmux-256color" to: set -g
> default-terminal "xterm-256color"
>
> This solved the problem. Removing this line altogether also worked but
> it seemed better to be explicit.

It works for me.
Note: after changed the settings, you might need run

```
tmux kill-server
```

to make the changes take effect.

Answer (score 13):

A lot of answers have not worked for me but I finally found this Gist that works for MacOs.  The focus here is on RGB colors but I think that the underlying cause of the colors being off and backspace not working when `set-option default-terminal "screen-256color"` is used in `.tmux.conf` is that your computer is missing some information about the `tmux` terminal that you have to install manually.  This is a more robust and comprehensive solution than adding lines of code here and there to different config files and praying that everything works.

https://gist.github.com/bbqtd/a4ac060d6f6b9ea6fe3aabe735aa9d95

The idea is that MacOS doesn't naturally have an up to date ncurses program/doesn't have a correct description of the tmux terminal so you have to download and install it yourself.  These steps are taken directly from the Gist:

Make sure that `tic` (which is a tool for installing terminal info) is located in `/usr/bin`:

```
$ which tic
/usr/bin/tic
```

in my case it wasn't so I added

```
export PATH="/usr/bin:$PATH"
```

to my `.zshrc`

get the terminal descriptions:

```
$ curl -LO https://invisible-island.net/datafiles/current/terminfo.src.gz && gunzip terminfo.src.gz
```

Install them (do this as root (by prepending `sudo`) if you want to do it for all users):

```
$ /usr/bin/tic -xe tmux-256color terminfo.src
$ sudo /usr/bin/tic -xe tmux-256color terminfo.src
```

This error:

```
"terminfo.src", line 1650, terminal 'pccon+base': enter_bold_mode but no exit_attribute_mode
"terminfo.src", line 1650, terminal 'pccon+base': enter_reverse_mode but no exit_attribute_mode
```

is nothing tow worry about.

now

```
infocmp -x tmux-256color
```

should display some output
then add

```
set-option default-terminal "tmux-256color"
```

to `~/.tmux.conf`.

Make sure that at least one of these outputs is not missing:

```
$ tmux info | grep -e RGB -e Tc
```

And if they're both missing you have to do something like one of these three:

```
set-option -a terminal-overrides ",XXX:RGB"
set-option -a terminal-overrides ",*256col*:RGB"
set-option -a terminal-overrides ",alacritty:RGB"
```

where xxx is something like xterm-256color (your terminal type), the asterisks do patter matching, and the last one recognizes that it could be something else (mine is `xterm-kitty`) but I'm not sure exactly what to put here because the `grep`s I did for Tc returned true.

Ok that should do it! The code is taken directly from the Gist so all credit goes to that author.  Including it here in case the Gist somehow gets deleted.

Answer (score 7):

This worked in my case.

1. Add `set -g default-terminal "xterm-256color"` to tmux.conf
2. Reopen tmux session.

Answer (score 1):

For me, backspace was working in vim, but not in vim + tmux. [This answer from SuperUser](https://superuser.com/a/793283/1012390) fixed it:

> You can map the backspace key to what you need, like Kevin said. It looks like you need to map it to ^? (rather than ^H)
>
> To do that, use the following command:
>
> ```
> stty erase "^?"
> ```
>
> This can be added to your startup scripts (.login or .tcshrc or .bashrc, or other files, depending on which shell you use).

Answer (score 1):

I had backspace issues and [this solution](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/issues/1257#issuecomment-581378716) worked for me:

```bash
brew install ncurses
infocmp tmux-256color > ~/tmux-256color.info
tic -xe tmux-256color tmux-256color.info
```

Then restart `tmux`.

Comment: Simple and to the point -- this worked for me, with iTerm.